# Why I am not getting the stored value of $a0 from stack?? I am only getting the changed value

Tags: mips

```
string_insert:

addi $sp, $sp, -200
sw $a0, 0($sp)
#insertion point
add $t0, $a0, $a2

lb $t2, ($a1)
loop:
  beq $t2, $zero, end # If the character is null, exit the loop
  sb $t2, ($t0)           # Store the current character at the insertion point
  addi $t0, $t0, 1        # Increment the insertion point
  addi $a1, $a1, 1        # Move to the next character of the second string
  lb $t2, ($a1)           # Load the next character of the second string
  j loop

# End of loop
end:
sb $zero, ($t0)
lw $a0, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 200
li $v0, 4
move $a0, $a0
syscall
jr $ra
```

$a0 contains hello and after storing it to stack, I am changing it to heabc. But after retriving it I'm not getting hello.

Comment: Look again. The address you stored to the stack is the same address you loaded at the end. What changed is the data stored at that address.

Comment: Use single step debugging to observe the effect of every instruction, especially watch the `sb`s and see memory change, byte by byte.

Comment: I don't know why but the same mips code is working in the Mars simulator in my friend's system but not in mine. Like jr $ra or if conditions are not working in my system but does work in his. Any idea why this happened? ( We are using same Mars version)

Comment: Remember, the thing you stored to the stack is not the string "hello". It's the address of some memory that holds a string. The function changes the contents of the memory, but the address didn't change. So your code is working just fine. (My guess is that your friend's code is not modifying the string.) Step through the code in a debugger to see what is happening.